# Have I written the INSERT query correctly?

Tags: php, mysqli

Here is my code:

```
        <?php
       include('admin/class.php');
```

Here is my db connection:

```
       $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "timesheet1234");
```

Here is the action for save button:

```
        if(isset($_POST['save']))
        {  
        $user=$_SESSION['user'];
        $sel =$_POST["selpro"];
        $mon =$_POST["mon"];
        $tue =$_POST["tue"];
        $wed =$_POST["wed"];
        $thu =$_POST["thu"];
        $fri =$_POST["fri"];
        $sat =$_POST["sat"];
        $sun =$_POST["sun"];
```

Checking whether the $user is in db are not:

```
        $sql=mysqli_query($link,"select * from emp   
                       where username='".$_SESSION['user']."'");
        $res=mysqli_num_rows($sql);
```

Here it checks whether to insert are not:

```
        if($res==0)
        {
          $sql1 = mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO  emp SET username='$user',
         project code='$sel',mon=$mon,tue=$tue,wed=$wed,
                  thu=$thu,fri=$fri,sat=$sat,sun=$sun");
```

Here the problem comes:

```
         if($sql1){
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
         echo "alert('TimeSheet Saved..!')";
         echo "</script>";
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
         echo "window.location='my_tm.php'";
         echo "</script>";
         }
          else
          {
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
         echo "alert('Some Error Occured ! Retry..!')";
         echo "</script>";
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
         echo "window.location='my_tm.php'";
         echo "</script>";
         }
         }
         }
         ?>
```

Comment: Here is the problem - I could not see any problem.

Comment: but data is not inserted into db

Comment: javascript is not php

Comment: I don't want to help you BCOZ of your title. Also, i see no questions here. downvoted and flagged

Comment: and the problem is......

Comment: problem is it is not entering into if(sql1) condition.....directly it is going to else condition...

Comment: Looks like you've posted this question three times. Please only ask once, since repeated asks wastes other people's time. Downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Isnt the problem with `if($res==0)`? Because you check if the session user is in the database and store the number of rows in `$res`. So I would guess that you want to insert the query when `$res==1` (one user) and not when there is no user.

Also normally you have complete control over your session variables. So once you store a user in there, you can trust that its there. Unless ofcourse you made mistakes on the authentication process.

Also in your javascript code you want to use `window.location.href='my_tm.php` to change the url and not just `window.location`

Comment: no if in the db dat user is there no need to insert the data...

Comment: if that user is unavailable at dat time we should insert the user data

Comment: Ok, then perhaps the other options in my answer. Or explain what actually is going wrong. What do you expect to happen and what is happening

Comment: actually in my code there shud be update query if there is user in db...

Comment: if there is no user it should insert the new user

Comment: but wat happening is it is updating the exisisted user...

Comment: but it is not inserting the new user into my db

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your insert query

```
 $sql1 = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO  emp SET username='$user',
         `project code`='$sel',mon='$mon',tue='$tue',wed='$wed',
                  thu='$thu',fri='$fri',sat='$sat',sun='$sun'",$link);
```

The `project code` column has space

Comment: no it is not working...

Comment: @SweetmouniMounika I have edited the query. try that

Comment: ya u are saying abt the above query nly na... i tried it but it is not working....

Comment: @SweetmouniMounika  what do you see `echo mysqli_num_rows($res);`

Comment: zero rows... it is properly working upto running the query but problem is in checking if condition it is returning false and executing else part...